# Add CATextLayer on Top of NSImageView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsimage

I'm trying to display text on top of an NSImage.I use the following code

```
                    let myTextLayer = CATextLayer()
                    myTextLayer.string = "My text"
                    myTextLayer.foregroundColor = NSColor.cyan.cgColor
                    myTextLayer.frame = self.img_view.bounds
                    self.img_view.layer=myTextLayer;
```

This keeps producing empty NSImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needs explicitly say `NSImageView` `wantsLayer` before use layers, like below

```
self.img_view.wantsLayer = true

let myTextLayer = CATextLayer()
myTextLayer.string = "My text"
myTextLayer.foregroundColor = NSColor.cyan.cgColor
myTextLayer.frame = self.img_view.bounds

self.img_view.layer.addSublayer(myTextLayer)
```